# Physical meaning of the Ising Hamiltonian

Tags: energy, hamiltonian, ising-model

I have question about the Ising model, specifically the Ising Hamiltonian. From what I have read, the Ising Hamiltonian describes the energy of the system of spins with a certain configuration. What I do not understand is why the Hamiltonian can become negative if it is indeed the energy of the system? What is the physical meaning of this Hamiltonian? Is it a proportional quantity to the energy of the system or how am I supposed to interpret it ? Thank you for all the answers

Comment: *What I do not understand is why the Hamiltonian can become negative if it is indeed the energy of the system?* Are you aware that the bound eigenstates of the Schrodinger Hamiltonian for a hydrogen atom are negative? The energy of the ground state is -13.6 eV.

Comment: Hello @G. Smith thank you for your quick response. I do not understand how the eigenstates or even a Hamiltonian can be negative. Can I just Offset the term and make it positive ? Which would mean that the these terms describe a general behavior but not a concrete quantity ? Or am I thinking wrong?

Comment: It’s common for non-relativistic total energy to be negative because potential energy (such as the electrostatic energy between a proton and an electron) can be negative. I don’t see why this would bother you. The relativistic energy including the mass-energy is positive.

Comment: Actually I'm writing my Theses about Ising Machines and I have a section where I explain the Ising model but I could not quite fathom how Hamiltonians could be negative if they're energy functions. I'm studying electrical engineering and I only deal with energy functions that positvie-definite, which makes me question negative Hamiltonians such as the Ising Hamiltonian

Comment: This is just standard classical electromagnetism. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_dipole–dipole_interaction). Negative energy just means a system has less energy than when its parts are separated infinitely far apart (and at rest). If you pretend the energy (not including mass-energy) is always positive you are obscuring this basic physics.

Comment: Thank you very much. This pretty much answers my question. But since you only commented I cannot upvote the answer? Is there an alternative way or is it okay for the question to stay unanswered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Negative energy is extremely common in nonrelativistic physics, there is nothing conceptually different about it than positive energy. I think it would be helpful to see a particularly simple example: in classical mechanics, the potential energy between two gravitating bodies is
$$U(r) = -G \frac{m_1 m_2}{r}$$
The physical content of this equation should be clear: the attraction between the two bodies is proportional to each of their masses, $G$ is a proportionality constant which fixes the units, and the energy decreases as the two bodies become closer (ie, as $r$ decreases, $U(r)$ becomes more negative). Here, it makes perfect sense that the energy is negative: it is sensible for $U(r)$ to be zero when the two bodies are infinitely far apart, so it must be negative for the energy to decrease as the bodies attract each other.

As for the Ising model, you are probably looking at Hamiltonians like
$$H = -J \sum_{\langle i, j \rangle} \sigma_i \sigma_j $$
Indeed, you can see by inspection that the energy is negative when all the spins point in the same direction (ie, $\sigma_i = +1$ for all $i$ or $\sigma_i = -1$ for all $i$). If t his really bothers you, and you cannot accept negative energies, then you can equally well choose the Hamiltonian
$$H' = -J \sum_{\langle i, j \rangle} (\sigma_i \sigma_j - 1)$$
which you can see by inspection differs from $H$ only by a constant. In statistical physics, an overall constant of energy does not affect any observable quantities, so you are free to choose either. In other words, there's no experiment that will tell you the absolute energy in the system, only differences, and this constant will therefore always cancel.

Perhaps it's worth remarking on why you might feel negative energy is so problematic -- I think this is possibly due to popular physics creating misconceptions. Indeed, there are situations where a "negative energy" would be really problematic in physics. The best example is general relativity, where absolute energies are indeed meaningful. But this is very far-afield from the Ising model, where you simply do not need to worry about negative energies.

Answer (score 2):

The Hamiltonian in this context is usually just the energy of the system.
Total energy is always defined up to a constant - and it can be any rational value (the values itself does not matter but rather the **differences in energy between different states**).

The important point is to understand that because there are electric forces between two spins, the state with the minimum energy (in the two-spin system) is the state in which the two spins are in the same direction.

In order to have specific values of energy to the system you need to choose some reference state and give it a specific energy value. In the Ising model, if the **energy difference between the two states in the two-spin system is $a$** than it is the convention to choose the energy value of the **high energy state** (i.e. the state in which the two spins **are not** in the same direction) to be $a/2$ and then it follows that the energy value of the **low energy state** (i.e. the state in which the two spins **are** in the same direction) is $-a/2$.